# Only scale selected bone's mesh scale

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature, scale

I'm new at Blender
As you can see on the image I want to scale only selected bone mesh but they scale all which are connected.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the next bone in the chain after the one you want to scale. Then go to the properties panel and go to the bone tab. Near the bottom there will be a 'Relations' heading. Under that heading there will be a checkbox for 'Inherit Scale'. Uncheck that and you should be good to go.